# How to create dynamic content with relative IDs using different buttons, inputs or links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

It seems to be easy, but it might be harder than it looks like, maybe. I've been having a hard time with this one.

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to create dynamic content with IDs, when clicking on any button, input or link using jQuery.

To explain better,

1. If .button-2 or .input-2 or .link-2 has been clicked, then the content dynamically created should be **Content-1** and not **Content-2** (I've got this part working right).
2. Then, If .button-1 or .input-1 or .link-1 gets clicked after, another content gets dynamically created and should be **Content-2** (and not **Content-1**) and so on... (this part is also working fine)
3. If there is only 3 different elements I'm targeting, then only 3 contents should be created and not more. Unless I add another different target element and so on... (**I need help with this**)
4. The target elements could (but is not necessary) be clicked as of an unorderly way and still have the content with an ordered ID. (This working fine too)

In other words, you don't have to click the target elements as of an orderly way to have the content with an ordered ID.

[Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/hxg0md7p/7/)

This code was created as an example of the main code

```js
$(function() {
  var num = 1;

  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $("<div />").attr("id", num).text("Content-" + num)
      .appendTo($(".inner"));
    num++;
  });
});
```

```css
.inner {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.inner div {
  background: #d0cfcf;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="button-1">btn 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="button-2">btn 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="button-3">btn 3</button>
</div>
<div class="container-2">
  <input type="text" class="input-1" value="click me">
  <input type="text" class="input-2" value="click on me too">
</div>
<div class="container-3">
  <a href="#" class="link-1">Click here</a>
  <a href="#" class="link-1">Click here</a> 
</div>


<div class="inner"></div>
```

This question has been updated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Counting the buttons to answer the original question:

```js
$(function() {
  var num = 1;
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".inner").children().length>=$(".container").children().length) return
    $("<div />").attr("id", num).text("Content-" + num)
      .appendTo($(".inner"));
    num++;
  });
});
```

```css
.inner {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.inner div {
  background: #d0cfcf;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button type="button">btn 1</button>
  <button type="button">btn 2</button>
  <button type="button">btn 3</button>
</div>

<div class="inner"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, but can another button(s) be added and create more content(s)?

Comment: So, the return keyword by it self located on the "if statement" line, will return false if there is more number of contents than the number of buttons?

Comment: I believe Mr. mplungjan is suggesting that you get the count of children inside .container and instead of returning a value immediately, you use this count together with a loop to generate the precise number of cloned elements you need.

Comment: I get what you're saying.

Comment: @jQueryster Not sure what you mean. Please update your question with more HTML to show the stating point

Comment: @mplungjan sure.

Comment: @jQueryster to answer the first comment. If there are the same number or more of content as buttons, the function does nothing

Comment: @mplungjan I've just updated the question. i hope is not so confusing.

Comment: @jQueryster it is. What is the code supposed to do with the other 2 containers?

Comment: @mplungjan I suspected it. Well, the children elements from the other other 2 containers can be target elements to create content. Is there anything you can do to accomplish it?

Comment: I am sorry - I do not understand what you are trying to do

Comment: You provided a solution for the original question. Fair enough! I appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

Here's a hardcoded, simple example.

```
var num = 1;

$( "button" ).on( "click", function() {

if( num === 1) {

num++;
$( "<div />" ).attr( "id", num ).text( "Content-" + num ).appendTo( $( ".inner" ) );
return;
}

if( num === 2) {

num--;
$( "<div />" ).attr( "id", num ).text( "Content-" + num ).appendTo( $( ".inner" ) );
return;
}

if( num === 3) {

num--;
$( "<div />" ).attr( "id", num ).text( "Content-" + num ).appendTo( $( ".inner" ) );
return;
}

});
```

Comment: That might work with 3 buttons only, but what about if I have 20 buttons? That will be a  lot of code not looking good